# Can someone explain this haskell function to count occurences of char in a string

Tags: haskell

I am mostly unsure about what **x'** represents here. Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
count :: Char -> String -> Int 
count x xs = length [x'|x'<-xs, x==x']
```

Comment: `x'` is a variable that represents the `Char`s in the `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`x'` is a variable that represents the `Char`s in the `String`.

You can see this list comprehension as something similar in Python:

```
len([y for y in xs if x == y])
```

It will thus enumerate over the `Char`s in the string, and check if the `Char` matches with the query `x`, if that holds it will add that to the list.

In Python however, an identifier can not contain a quote. In haskell that is often used to mimic the [*prime symbol* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) to denote that something is similar to the item without the prime. It thus means that `x'` is somehow a bit similar to `x`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation another question i have is how would you generalize the type of this function?

Comment: @jDownUnder: take a look at the [**`Eq`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq).

Comment: after taking a look i tried defining it as a -> [a] -> Int but i get an error on the "ex6.hs:5:40: error:
    * No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            countocc :: forall a. a -> [a] -> Int"

But i am still a bit confused why and how to solve it

Comment: jDownUnder: well as the exception says, you need to add the type constraint, so `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int`.

Comment: ah so if we are using the == then we use eq then the type and i see there is others like Ord etc for other expressions would i be right in saying that?

Comment: @jDownUnder: yes, you can see a typeclass as what is in OO known as an interface, `Eq a` means that `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` can be called on items of type `a`.